# Is it possible to spoof screen size or resolution in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser, resolution, spoofing

I have a very unique screen size which makes me particularly vulnerable to fingerprinting.

Is it possible to make it seem like my screen is the standard 1920x1080, without actually changing the window or view resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Firefox supports [Responsive Design Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_Mode). From the keyboard: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> on macOS).

[image: Firefox RDM]