# Spoof my resolution, scroll position or viewport

Tags: google-chrome, scrolling, greasemonkey

I very much dislike certain websites that constantly load stuff as you're scrolling down. Even worse, some of them "unload" them and you have to wait again when you scroll back up.

ChatGPT and other sources don't have good workarounds. Even just zooming out in the browser is limited to like 20% so you can't go far enough to load large amounts of content.

I realise this won't be feasible for all websites, but I'd like to do it for some particularly egregious ones, some kind of tampermonkey script or chrome extension to trick the website into thinking I have a hugely long portrait monitor, and also not tell the website exactly what part if the page I'm looking at, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Chrome browser, but [that feature](https://superuser.com/questions/1475238/is-it-possible-to-spoof-screen-size-or-resolution-in-firefox) is built into Firefox: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> (on Windows or Linux OS) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Opt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> (on MacOS) to enter [Responsive Design Mode](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/responsive_design_mode/index.html).

Set the desired screen dimensions at top, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the page is displayed as you want, with the ability to scroll around if larger than physical screen size.

There are also [add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=zoom%20image) to enable zooming images, text or both when the site makes that difficult.